# Flutter Streambuilder is duplicating items

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have a StreamBuilder connected to a List and the List gets its data from Firebase, but every there is an Event in my Database the items in my Streambuilder get Duplicated.

Here is my StreamBuilder code:

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: masterListStart().asStream(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    //return coursesList.length == 0
                    return finishedLoadingList
                        ? ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: storysList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              //
                              StoryItems data = storysList[index];
                              //
                              return StoryItems(
                                data: data,
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        : CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
```

How I can prevent the StreamBuilder from doing this?

Comment: Where `finishedLoadingList` variable ?

Comment: It's in my setState after retrieving is completed. The data gets shown but duplicates itself when the databases changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `finishedLoadingList`, you can simply check your snapshot connectionState as following

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: masterListStart().asStream(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    //return coursesList.length == 0
    return (ConnectionState.done == snapshot.connectionState) ? ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: storysList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        //
        StoryItems data = storysList[index];
        //
        return StoryItems(
          data: data,
        );
      },
    ) : CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
),
```

Comment: Sir, your are the best, thank you so much, it works perfectly fine. Best Regards

Comment: Glad it helped! Happy coding

Comment: Thank you sir, you to

Comment: Hello, I started the Code again but the problem is happening again I tried to rebuild everything and deinstalled the App checked the Code etc. but looks like it is happening again. Any other solutions?

Comment: Hello. It may depend on your code architecture. Will try to help you later. Bit busy

Comment: I have an idea. If it is in the nature of the Streambuilder to stream things I could let him clean the list every time an event happens and let him add the data to the clean list right?

Comment: Hello, sir cleaning the list before adding data works. So no need for help anymore but still thanks for the first solutions it helped me improve the code.

Comment: You video on Ytube was great. Liked the way you explain

Comment: Thank you. By the way sorry for asking you to help me again and then solving it by myself didn't meant to waste your time.